# Buffering Canvas in onDraw() method

Tags: android, buffer, android-canvas, ondraw

How can I buffer a Circle drawn with drawCircle canvas method?

I need to draw two circles, then an arc when the user sweep his finger on the circles.
So, the two circles will be always the same, but the angle (drawn by the drawArc method) will be always different.
I want to buffer this circles and not drawing them over and over again...
I got this code working, but I suppose that it can be better.

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas); 
        /*first circle*/
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, mRadius2, getGradient(OUTER_CIRCLE_COLOR));
        /*second circle*/
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, mRadius, getGradient(INNER_CIRCLE_COLOR));
        rectF.set(getWidth()/2- mRadius2, getHeight()/2 - mRadius2, getWidth()/2 + mRadius2, getHeight()/2 + mRadius2);
        /*draw the arc*/
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, 180, this.getSweepAngle(), true,p);
        invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Circle class with an onDraw() method.  In your custom view, create a collection of Circle objects and add the 2 circles.  In the onDraw method of the custom view, call the onDraw of each circle.

```
class Circle(){

   int mX;
   int mY;
   int mRadius;
   int mColour;

   void Circle(int x, int y, int radius, int Colour){
       this.mX = x;
       this.mY = y;
       this.mRadius = radius;
       this.mColour = colour;
   }

   void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
       canvas.drawCircle(this.mX, this.mY, this.mRadius, getGradient(this.mColour));
   }

}
```

In your view:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas); 

    for (Circle circle:circles){
        circle.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    rectF.set(getWidth()/2- mRadius2, getHeight()/2 - mRadius2, getWidth()/2 + mRadius2, getHeight()/2 + mRadius2);

 /*draw the arc*/
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, 180, this.getSweepAngle(), true,p);
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: with your code I will drawing the circles every time that the onDraw event is fired. Isn't there a way to just keep the circles on the background? I mean, without drawing them every time?

Comment: You could create a bitmap, draw the circles to the bitmap then draw the bitmap to the canvas.  Remember that a canvas is just a store for your drawing calls.  It is NOT the surface you draw onto.

Comment: This is not answer to question but basically just refactoring of the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bitmap with same size as canvas, and draw the circles into the bitmap.

In the `onDraw()` you use `canvas.drawBitmap()` to restore the circels in the canvas.

However, this only justifies when you have complex or heavy shapes being drawn in the canvas. For two circles I'm not sure that you will get any improvement.

**Example**

First prepare the bitmap with circles:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();

/*first circle*/
canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, mRadius2, getGradient(OUTER_CIRCLE_COLOR));
/*second circle*/
canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, mRadius, getGradient(INNER_CIRCLE_COLOR));
```

use it on `onDraw()`

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas); 

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

 /*draw the arc*/
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, 180, this.getSweepAngle(), true,p);
    invalidate();
}
```

Regards